# Metadata updating models from database first in Entity Framework does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add some more validation message annotations to models (all models here are generated by database first), so I did use metadata by the help from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation. No models are updated, and but build fails and warning is shown instead:

> Error 6046: Unable to generate function import return type of the store function 'fn_diagramobjects'.
>
> Error CS1061 'Account' does not contain a definition for 'ConfirmPassword' and no extension method 'ConfirmPassword' accepting a first argument of type 'Account' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    project-asp-mvc D:.NET demo\Project\project-asp-mvc\Controllers\UserController.cs  85  Active

This is my model generated from the database:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Account
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Account()
    {
        this.Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
    }

    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> role_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

**Metadata.cs**:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace project_asp_mvc.Models
{
    public class AccountMetadata
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Username con not be longer than 50")]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [NotMapped]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Please confirm your password again")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**PartialClasses.cs**

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

 namespace project_asp_mvc.Models
 {
    [MetadataType(typeof(AccountMetadata))]
    public partial class Account
    {
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did these lines of code come from in the AccountMetadata class.

```
[Required]
[NotMapped]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Please confirm your password again")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

You appear to have added annotations to a property that doesn't exit in the account class.
I suggest you remove these lines and try again.

Comment: If I remove it, so how can I confirm the 2 passwords ?

Comment: 1 miracle at a time. Right now it doesn't even build. Let's get it running to make sure there's no more problems, then go from there.

Comment: Build success, but it still exists the warning, nothing updated: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning  Error 6046: Unable to generate function import return type of the store function 'fn_diagramobjects'. The store function will be ignored and the function import will not be generate